# PHP Slim with Firebase JWT

Tags: php, firebase, jwt, middleware, slim

I am trying to integrate Firebase Auth with PHP Slim (JWT) without any luck. I login using my firebase user and save my token correctly. Then I set my midleware.php like this:

```
$app->add(new Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "ignore" => ["/countries","/faqs"],
    "secret" => $secrets,
    "secure" => false
]));
```

where $secrets is the kid coming from securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com. However I keep getting an error 401 not authorized.

Same code works when I try it with a custom $secret and custom jwt. Does Firebase need something extra in the JwtAuthentication?

Comment: you're not providing enough info. What do you mean with **$secrets is the kid coming from..."** I believe you meant key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was how JwtAuthentication from Tuupola handles the kid (it is actually kid - key id which comes from googles [public keys](https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com)).

In vanilla PHP, I had to get the secrets from google, then split it into arrays before using it. However, this is all done by Tuupola internally, which caused my issue.

The correct Middleware for Slim 4 to work with Firebase Auth is the following:

```php
return function (App $app) {
    $app->add(CorsMiddleware::class);

    $container = $app->getContainer();
    
    $rawPublicKeys = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com');
    $keys = json_decode($rawPublicKeys, true);

    $app->add(new Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
        "ignore" => ["/api/records/countries","/faqs","/","/answer"],
        "algorithm" => ["RS256"],
        "header" => "X-Authorization",
        "regexp" => "/Bearer\s+(.*)$/i",
        "secret" => $keys,
        "secure" => false
        }
    ]));
};
```

Comment: Do you used firebase javascript sdk on the client side to log in the users then this in server side code to check the token?

Comment: This is used by a mobile app which uses Slim 4 as a backend. User logs in the app using their firebase credentials and then their token is used in the backend to allow access to the Rest API.